# Looking for a settings prop - auto insert function arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say we have a `function foo(bar,baz){}`. I am looking for a setting that allows when I select `foo` from autocomplete, the editor to be populated with `foo(bar, baz)`.

I remember that there was such setting, but I didn't like it initially and I disable it. Now I cannot find it and I will appriciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable

> Javascript > Suggest: Complete Function Calls

and same for Typescript

Comment: That was it. It is sea of settings, and sometimes it is hard not to drawn :)